# How to rewind the bitstream pointer?

Tags: python, bitstream

I'm decoding a binary file byte-by-byte. No problem in reading variables that have a size which is a multiple of 8 bits, such as:

```
#encoder
bitstream.add(data_id, 16)

#decoder
data_id = struct.unpack('>H', in_file.read(2))[0]
```

What if the data I'm willing to decode isn't a multiple of 8 bits?
For example, I add in the bitstream the following data:

```
#encoder
bitstream.add(F1, 1)
bitstream.add(F2, 1)
bitstream.add(F3, 1)
bitstream.add(F4, 1)
bitstream.add(F5, 1)
if (aflag):
    bitstream.add(F6_a, 1)
    bitstream.add(F7, 1)
else:
    bitstream.add(F6_b, 1)
```

If the if evaluates to True I have to read 7 bits, otherwise I read 6 bits.

```
#decoder
# read 8 bits
data = struct.unpack('>B', in_file.read(1))[0]
F1 = data >> 7
F2 = data >> 6 & 0b01
F3 = data >> 5 & 0b001
F4 = data >> 4 & 0b0001
F5 = data >> 3 & 0b00001
if (aflag):
  # first data block
  F6_a = data >> 2 & 0b000001
  F7 = data >> 1 & 0b1
else:
  # second data block
  F6_b = data >> 2 & 0b000001
```

In the `first data block` case, I'm reading 7 bits and I have a spare 1. 
In the `second data block` case, I'm reading 6 bits and I have 2 spare bits. After these 8 bits, I have variables which all are multiple of 8 bits or groups of variables which together have size which is a multiple of 8 bits. So, I'm looking for a solution that does not imply to read all subsequent variables accounting for the spare bits.

In the `first data block` case, how can I set the bitstream pointer to the 7th bit, so that I can read the following data as if there have no been spare bits in the previous read?

Comment: Your data stream MUST include the information to work out during decoding whether there are 6 or 7 bits to use, otherwise how would it be possible to decide whether to skip 1 or 2 bits.

Comment: There is no "bitstream pointer" when directly calling `.read()` on a file.  Does this `bitstream` module you're using not have the ability to handle reading?

Comment: Please edit a [mre] into your question. If you don't know what a [mre] is please click the link to [mre] and read.

Comment: From the [bitstream documentation](https://boisgera.github.io/bitstream/installation/), it doesn't look like it supports a `seek()` method. I suppose you could add one since it's open source.

Comment: There's a [`bitstring`](https://pypi.org/project/bitstring/) module that works with files and supports reading bits from arbitrary positions in them which might work better for you.

Comment: @barny: the variable "aflag" is decoded in the previous steps, so the info on how many bits to skip is included in the data stream. Or am I missing anything?